# Regex to return contents of word and bracket

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

What Regex pattern would I need to extract the contents of a pair of parentheses in PHP which have a preceding specific string?

So if I have a statement

```
@includelayout( 'cms.layout.nav-header' )
```

I only need the contents of the parentheses that are directly preceded by @includelayout.

So I just want it to return:

```
'cms.layout.nav-header'
```

I am currently using:

```
preg_match('/(?&lt;!\w)(?:\s*)@includelayout((?:\s*)?\(.*)/', $value, $matches);
```

which gives me

```
array (size=2)
    0 => string '@includelayout( 'output.layout.nav-header' )' (length=46)
    1 => string '( 'output.layout.nav-header' )' (length=30)
```

but I just can't get it to not return the parentheses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get the matched group from index 1:

```
(?<=@includelayout\()([^)]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aL9mD0/1)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(?<=@includelayout\\()([^)]*)/i";
$str = "@includelayout( 'cms.layout.nav-header' )";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to match the contents within paranthesis without  leading and the following spaces inside paranthesis,

```
@includelayout\(\s*\K.*?(?=\s*\))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gA3pT6/7)

If you want to match all the characters which are enclosed within `()` preceeded by the string `@includelayout` then you could try the below.

```
@includelayout\(\K[^)]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gA3pT6/8)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = "@includelayout( 'cms.layout.nav-header' )";
$regex = '~@includelayout\(\K[^)]*~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=>  'cms.layout.nav-header'
```